# Get ID from Facebook Page URL in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want to open a Facebook page by Facebook application In iOS using page url. Is there any way to get 'Facebook page id' programmatically  from 'Facebook page url' in Objective C?

Comment: Yes it is Like https://www.facebook.com/Cristiano just remove `https://www.facebook.com/` and you will have Page ID.

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"fb://profile/", @"Cristiano"]];
But it is not working